# How to find a tangent line of a path SnapSVG.js / SVG

Tags: javascript, math, svg

I have an svg path that I want to animate an arrow travelling across, as represented by this diagram:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFk2L.gif

A conceptual answer or references to other libraries that work with SVGs may suffice.

My first thoughts to a solution would be to find two points on the path and find the angle between them; this solution would also make finding the direction of the arrowhead easy, because the angle between the arrow's position on the path, and a point slightly further along a path would already be pointed in the correct direction.

Comment: How are you animating the path?  What does your code look like?

Comment: Well, it looks something like this [seashell experiment I made](http://zombiehippie.com/incomplete/html/pathfollow-snapsvg.html)